# Can't get InAppPurchase receipt in correct format

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I am trying to get an receipt using in-app purchase.

```
   NSURL *receiptURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL];
   NSData *receipt = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:receiptURL];
   NSString *receiptDataString = [receipt base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
   NSLog(@"%@",receiptDataString);
```

When I try to decode the output it shows some strange text, not looking like json format receipt.

When i try to make a POST request to https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt to send my receipt data and password get an error.

> Array (   [status] => 21002   [exception] =>
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException )

How to get a right receipt?

Comment: The base64 string will contain + characters. These need to be encoded as %2B

Comment: @Paulw11 Thank's for reply! When I replaced + characters with %2B the same problems appears.                                                        receiptDataString=[receiptDataString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@"%2B"];